# A question about lattice distribution and characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, characteristic-functions

A random variable $X$ has a lattice distribution if the support of $X$ is $\{a+nb: n\in Z\}$. Let $X$ have characteristic function $\phi$.
I have proved earlier that $X$ has a lattice distribution $\iff$ $|\phi(t)| = 1$ for some $t$

## The question now is if $|\phi(t)| = 1$ and $|\phi(t')| = 1$ for $t/t'=irrational$, prove that $P(X=c) = 1$.

My attempt:

$|\phi(t)| = 1\iff E[e^{iXt}]=1 \iff tX$ mod $2\pi = \theta \iff X = \frac{\theta}{t}+\frac{2\pi n}{t}$
$|\phi(t')| = 1\iff E[e^{iXt'}]=1 \iff t'X$ mod $2\pi = \theta' \iff X = \frac{\theta'}{t'}+\frac{2\pi n}{t'}$

When $X = \frac{\theta'}{t'}+\frac{2\pi n}{t'}, E[e^{iXt}] = E[e^{it(\frac{\theta'}{t'}+\frac{2\pi n}{t'})}] = 1\iff \frac{t}{t'}\in Z$.
By symmetry, $\frac{t'}{t}\in Z\implies t'=-t$ because $t\neq t'$

So why can't the support of $X$ be $\{\frac{\theta}{t}+\frac{2\pi n}{t}:n\in Z\}\cup \{-\frac{\theta'}{t}-\frac{2\pi n}{t}:n\in Z\}$ and why does $X$ have to be a single value a.s.? Thanks and appreciate a hint!

Comment: If $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\frac12$ then $\phi(t)=\cos(t)$ which equals $1$ infinitely often.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. I get that $\phi(t)=cos(t)$ and $|\phi(t)|=1$ i.o. but not sure how that leads to $P(X=c)=1$? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't${}$.

Comment: $t \neq t'$ is not good enough. If $t/t'$ is irrational then the conclusion is true.

Comment: You are right, edited the question.